# How to solve the diophantine equation $x^y = y^x $?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I know this might be an obvious question as we all know that the answers (beside $(x,y)=(1,1)$) are $(x,y)=(2,4)$ but the problem is, how is this exactly solved?

Tags might be inaccurate so feel free to edit my question at will.

By the way so far I tried this:

$x^y = y^x \rightarrow y\log x=x\log y $

Later on,I tried to draw their graphs and see where they intercept,but well ... no use.

A hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Prime factorization. Note that there's no addition in sight.

Comment: Any ordered pair of the form $(r,r)$ for $r \in \mathbb{R}$ is a solution.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sorry if I'm asking such a question,but what is a prime factorization?Actually I don't study math books in English and that's why I can't guess the meanings :D

Comment: @FuriousMathematician please google it.

Comment: @mweiss Obviously that's a trivial solution, but are there others that you can derive?

Comment: @IvoTerek Thanks for the edit.But I want an answer that somehow relates to the Number Theory the link you've included does not relate to such a thing.Actually I'm not good at limits and function so I'd really prefer an easier answer if possible

Comment: @FuriousMathematician: Why ask for an Answer that "somehow relates to the Number Theory" if prime factors are such a mystery that you "can't guess the meanings"?  I see the smiley emoticon, but it seems you having a laugh at our expense.

Comment: But the behaviour of $\frac{\ln t}{t}$ is basic calculus, kid stuff.

Comment: Instead of plotting $x^y$ and $y^x$, why not plot $x^{1/x}$ and, oh, $y^{1/y}$?